# How to use burnside lemma?

Tags: combinatorics

> How would you use burnside lemma to find the number of circular arrangements
>   possible of 2 blue items, 2 red items, and 3 yellow items assuming
>   that items of same color are indistinguishable?

I know for burnside lemma you first need to find the number of actions that keep the colors fixed, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're looking at the action of the cyclic group of order 7 on the set of (ordered) configurations of 2 blue, 2 red, and 3 yellow items.  There are ${7 \choose{2,2,3}} = \frac{7!}{2!2!3!}=210$ of these.

We want to know the number of orbits.  According to Burnside, this equals the average number of fixed points of the group action.

The identity fixes all 210 configurations, but the other six rotations do not fix any.  So the average is $\frac{1\cdot 210 + 6\cdot 0}{7} = 30$.

Of course, Burnside is overkill here; we can just observe that every configuration rotates into exactly six others.

Comment: How did you find that none of the other six rotations fix any configuration?

Comment: @user2612743 7 is prime, so a rotation must either identify all objects, or none of them.  But none of our configurations are monochromatic.

Comment: In other cases where the number is different (for example, 2 blue, 2 red, and 2 yellow) how would you find the number of fixed configurations?

Comment: @user2612743 For 2 blue, 2 red, 2 yellow, there are several cases.  The total number of configurations is ${6\choose{2,2,2}}=90$.  There is an identity rotation with 90 fixed points, two order 6 rotations with 0 fixed points, two order 3 rotations with 0 fixed points, and an order 2 rotation with $3!=6$ fixed points (the configurations with same colors opposite).  So we get $\frac{90+6}{6}=16$ orbits in this case.

Comment: I think I am understanding now. My only remaining question is how you found the number of fixed points from the order of the rotation.

Comment: @user2612743 Well, you think about it.  If you have an order 3 rotation that fixes a configuration, then there are going to be two groups of three items, where each group is all the same color.  This can't happen if there are three colors (though it could if we were counting 3 blue/2 red for example).